# bash script- printing the absolute path of all running jar

Tags: bash, jar, path, centos6

To printing all running jar on the server, the command is below:

```
ps -aux|grep java
```

But I want to get the output like below so that I can know the absolute path of running jars in the system:

```
Running_jar Absolute_path    
test.jar  /var/www/html/test/
test2.jar /var/www/html/test2/
```

Can anyone help how I can achieve this output with any bash command?

Comment: Please provide input and expected output

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have shared my expected output and that is:
   `Running Jar | Absolute path of jar
    test.jar  /var/www/html/test/
    test2.jar /var/www/html/test2/`
I just need to know the bash script from which i got the expected output:
i know a similar script ps -auxwwwe|grep java , by using this command I can know the absolute path of running jar, but couldn't get the output i want.

Answer (score 2):

`pwdx` is the command you'd need for that :

> pwdx - report current working directory of a process

Syntax is : `pwdx <pid_of_process>`

Comment: `pwdx` and you are lifesavers!